# Restore windows explore.exe using cmd

Tags: windows

How to restore a unstale Windows explore.exe using command prompt

I use the follow which doesn't work

\expand C:\i386\explorer.ex_ c:\Windows\explorer.exe

Comment: are you talking abut a plain cmd window? 
or are you talking about safemode?

Comment: yes cmd window using commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the letter of your CD/DVD drive if you are exporting from disc, e.g.:

```
expand D:\i386\explorer.ex_ %systemroot%\explorer.exe
```